# Cakephp redirect on error

Tags: php, cakephp

So we all know these `Error missing controller` or any other error that `CakePHP` can throw.

Now my question may be fairly simple but i could not find any documentation on the subject.

How do i redirect to a `404 not found` or a `500 execption` page (meaning how do i redirect to a costum page) if an execption should be found?

in my config/core.php i found this:

```
    Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

However im not sure what i  should change it to?

Comment: Define "redirect"! And please always mention your exact CakePHP version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
'renderer' => 'Test',
'log' => true
));
```

Create file Cake/Error/Test.php

```
<?php
class Test {
    public function __construct(Exception $exception) {
        header('Location: /');die();
    }
}
```

Missing Controller error you can prevent with router. Create last router rule:

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'e404'));
```