# how to redirect page if action is not found in cake php 2.X

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

how can i redirect the page if action doesn't exist. right now cakephp shows a default View/errors/missing_action.ctp . Having Message:-

**(Page Not Found!
Looks like we could not find the Action (page) you were looking for. )**

I want to redirect my page whenever page is not found.
Can any one guide me how to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cakephp redirect on error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863587/cakephp-redirect-on-error)

Answer (score 1):

The "Missing Action" error is only shown in development mode. On the live server you should always change the setting `Configure::write('debug', 0);` in `/app/Config/core.php` (= Production Mode). In Production Mode the 404 will be rendered. You can change/define the template in `/app/View/Errors/`. To change the cake default error behavior, you can create your own error controller. Just copy the file `lib/Cake/Controller/CakeErrorController.php` to `app/Controller/CakeErrorController.php` and make your modifications or redirects in this file...

Comment: i have tried to redirects in this app/Controller/CakeErrorController file but it is not working. if possible can you please tell me how to achieve that ?
it still shows the text wriiten in /app/View/Errors/missing_action.ctp

Comment: In `app/Controller/CakeErrorController.php` find the line `$this->_set(array('cacheAction' => false, 'viewPath' => 'Errors'));` and add after it this line `return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'yourdestinationcontroller', 'action' => 'yourdestinationaction'), '404');` Please also have a look at the [error handling](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html) in the book - maybe the solution of @utility is a better one, but I haven't used an own handler yet so I can't help you with that...

Answer (score 0):

Create AppController::appError(); to redirect to required page

```
   class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
        function missingAction($parameters) {
            $this->controller->redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain the above code?
and where should i add the above code?